# Android Studio 0.2.3 cannot resolve transitive aar dependencies

Tags: android-studio

We published iibrary artifacts in a remote maven repository, and include the repo URL and dependencies in another project. For example:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://..." }
}

dependencies{
  compile 'com.example.application:example-sdk:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

The example-sdk.aar depends on other transitive dependency JARs.

In Android Studio 0.2.1, all transitive dependencies can be downloaded and added in my project. I can view them in .iml and in the "External Libraries" folder. However, when I upgrade my Android Studio to 0.2.3, all transitive dependencies cannot be downloaded. Does anyone meet the same issue?