# Gradle for Android AAR Depending Upon AAR, Both In The Same Remote Repository?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

There are a few questions floating around regarding transitive dependencies with AAR files in Gradle:

- [Android Studio 0.2.3 cannot resolve transitive aar dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132581/android-studio-0-2-3-cannot-resolve-transitive-aar-dependencies)
- [Android Gradle library dependency with library dependency using Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061652/android-gradle-library-dependency-with-library-dependency-using-nexus)
- [Aar in repository. External dependency and NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440110/aar-in-repository-external-dependency-and-noclassdeffounderror)

I too have run into similar problems trying to set up transitive dependencies upon AAR files in a remote repository. I have App A, depending upon Library B, which in turn depends
upon Library C. Library C is in a Maven repo. Library B is in the same repo, with a POM
that contains the dependency upon Library C. App A has Library B in its dependencies. However, running **`gradle clean assembleDebug`** results in: "Module version [Library B] depends on libraries but is not a library itself".

I tried putting a bounty on one of those questions, hoping for clarity, with no luck.

My guess is that there are two possible sources of the difficulty that I and those with the aforementioned SO question are seeing:

1. Transitive AAR dependencies from a remote repository are simply broken
2. Transitive AAR dependencies from a remote repository work, but there is something off in our POM files, `build.gradle` files, or something that is breaking the dependencies

**The Question**: Does anyone know of an AAR artifact in some public repository (e.g., Maven Central), that depends upon another AAR artifact, also in the same public repository?

I am not interested in an AAR that depends upon something in a local repository, like an AAR in Maven Central that depends upon `com.android.support:support-v4`. In my case, if Library B and Library C are both in my local Maven repository (`~/.m2`), everything works fine.

According to Xav, [what I am doing should work](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/frugpmBwQt0). Hence, I am hoping that somebody can point me to a working example, so that I can use it to determine where the rest of us may be going wrong.

**NOTE**: I know that asking for off-site resources is verboten. In this case, I am not looking for the resource in its own right, but as an example of a working configuration, to help debug a non-working configuration. If you have another way of writing up an answer showing a working configuration, that'd be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: I would also add this related question to your list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507608 - It involves transitive dependencies in libray modules - although not in an AAR artifact.

Comment: Will you please mark an answer as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that my problem has cleared up with Gradle 1.9 and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+`. Leastways, I can no longer reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a public example but I have this scenario successfully setup in a internally-hosted Nexus repository. Here is the setup:

App - Android application project
LibraryB - Android library project
picasso - Open source library from Square (available on Maven Central)
LibraryA - Android library project

App depends on LibraryB and picasso
LibraryB depends on LibraryA

Here is the POM for LibraryB (downloaded from Nexus)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>LibraryB</artifactId>
   <version>0.1</version>
   <packaging>aar</packaging>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.example</groupId>
         <artifactId>LibraryA</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.1</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.squareup.picasso</groupId>
         <artifactId>picasso</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.1</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the build.gradle for LibraryB

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

version versionProp
group 'com.example'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url(exampleReleaseRepoUrl)
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.example:LibraryA:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: uri(exampleReleaseRepoUrl)) {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: uri(exampleSnapshotRepoUrl)) {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the POM for LibraryA (downloaded from Nexus)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>LibraryA</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <packaging>aar</packaging>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
         <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
         <version>19.0.0</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

The build.gradle for LibraryA is very similar to the one for LibraryB above.

The artifacts and POM for LibraryA and LibraryB were uploaded via the following Gradle command

```
gradle uploadArchives
```

The build.gradle for App looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url(exampleReleaseRepoUrl)
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.example:LibraryB:0.1'
}
```

If you need any further information let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding -- for some reason, I didn't get notified about your answer. I'll take a look at this ASAP try to compare POMs to figure out what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... well, my POMs look fine, comparing them with yours. I'll have to run some more tests, particularly after upgrading to the latest android plugin. Thanks!

Comment: I followed this but was not getting proper versioning and artifact naming, where can you configure this?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [Android Studio 0.4.4](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio044released) using .AAR dependencies is as straightforward as using .JAR dependencies. Just put it into `\libs` directory and reference it in `build.gradle`:

```
compile files('libs/YOUR_LIBRARY_NAME.aar')
```

Comment: Note that this question is with regards to a remote repository. Also note that bare AARs are frowned upon, AFAIK, for the same reason that bare JARs are -- version management. That being said, thanks for posting the info!

Comment: Actually I have this situation and the above solution does not work (AS 0.4.5, gradle 1.10, plugin 0.8.3). I had to use the 'flatDir' repository workaround. But unfortunately the transitive dependencies do not work.