# Gradle maven dependency not found if plugin is android-library

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

My objective is to compile a library that depends on other libraries (from HoloEverywhere), which are present in a remote maven repository, using Gradle and Android Studio (0.4.4).

If I set `apply plugin:` to `android` in the library's build.gradle, the remote maven dependencies are found, otherwise they are not (`apply plugin: 'android-library'`).

Here is my build.gradle with the android object omitted to save in space:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url 'http://192.241.191.41/repo'}
}

android {...}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.holoeverywhere:library:2.1.0@aar'
    compile 'org.holoeverywhere:addon-preferences:2.1.0@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

The error I get when I press "Sync Project with Gradle Files" in Android Studio is:

```
7:30:48 PM Failed to refresh Gradle project 'MyTopProject'
           Could not find org.holoeverywhere:library:2.1.0.
           Required by:
           MyTopProject:MyActualApp:unspecified > MyTopProject:MyMessedUpLib:unspecified
           Search in build.gradle files
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this behaviour expected? Should I do it in another way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: 7:30:48 PM Failed to refresh Gradle project 'MyTopProject'
           Could not find org.holoeverywhere:library:2.1.0.
           Required by:
           MyTopProject:MyActualApp:unspecified > MyTopProject:MyMessedUpLib:unspecified
           Search in build.gradle files

Comment: It might be this: I'm not sure if this thread has enough helpful advice for you to actually work around the problem though: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/Qv7E8mKxVFs  See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/Ll2JcCfgBsQ

Comment: That's odd. I [had transitive AAR problems previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551160/gradle-for-android-aar-depending-upon-aar-both-in-the-same-remote-repository), but they cleared up a while back. My [CWAC-Presentation project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation) depends upon [my CWAC-Layouts project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts) successfully (at least, the last I tried it).

Comment: Indeed if I let go the @aar, it doesn't complain anymore (but complains about com.nineoldandroids missing). Let me examine this a bit more...

Comment: `@aar` should only be needed if the project publishes multiple artifacts including a JAR, IIRC. Pirates are also known to add `@aar` to various things. :-)

Comment: So now, without any @aar, I'm back to the same issue but with com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0 which is present in maven central :/