# Can a maven artifact contain both a jar and an aar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have a library in the Maven Central Repository.  For the latest release I have pushed an .aar archive in addition to the normal .jar.

However I can't seem to get Android Studio to use the aar version of the library.  In my build.gradle file I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.mygroup:mylibrary:1.2.2'
}
```

This successfully fetched the jar file, but how do I get it to use the aar version of the library?  I tried a number of things, including (but not limited to):

```
compile 'com.mygroup:mylibrary:1.2.2@aar'
compile group: 'com.mygroup', name: 'mylibrary', version: '1.2.2', type: 'aar'
compile group: 'com.mygroup', name: 'mylibrary', version: '1.2.2', packaging: 'aar'
compile group: 'com.mygroup', name: 'mylibrary', version: '1.2.2', extension: 'aar'
```

But it always loads the jar.

Is Gradle expecting the artifact to contain just the AAR only (with a POM that matches)?  Do I need to create a separate artifact for the AAR version of the lib?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551160/gradle-for-android-aar-depending-upon-aar-both-in-the-same-remote-repository?rq=1) might help

Comment: Thanks for the link. That doesn't seem to offer any clues as to the answer to my particular problem though.

Comment: As for me `compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.3.4@aar'` works. Can you  compare this library and yours in maven central. Check pom and artifacts

Comment: What version of android gradle plugin do you use?

Comment: I'm using the latest Gradle plugin.  I see that your artifact has only the aar. And your pom references the aar.  So maybe I *do* just have to have a separate artifact or version for the aar.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Can you post the code you use to upload? Javadocs, AAR, JARs, etc are separate artifacts that can be uploaded under the same group/artifactId/version.

Comment: Why would the method of upload make a difference?  I haven't tested this for a long time.  I don't know whether this problem still exists.