# Can an Android AAR have a dependency on another AAR when built with Maven?

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin, transitive-dependency, aar

This is very similar to [Gradle for Android AAR Depending Upon AAR, Both In The Same Remote Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20551160/9636), but this question is Maven-specific.

If I have an `APK` project (app) with a dependency on an `AAR` project (lib1), can lib1 have a dependency on another `AAR` project (lib2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as long as you use a recent version of the Android Maven Plugin that supports that..

Comment: Giving you the honors as thanks for `maven-android-plugin`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Using [Android Archetypes](https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes) I created an `android-with-test` project, and then two `android-library-quickstart`s underneath it. I had to change the `android-library-quickstart` projects' packaging from `apklib` to `aar`. Then, I make lib1 depend upon lib2, and made my apk depend on lib1. `mvn clean install` succeeded.